# What are the subscribers to ngrx effects?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

My question relates to **ngrx effects** and **subscriptions**.

I am familiar with the concepts of observables and subscribing to them. I also know that ngrx effects are actually observables of actions. I also know that observables need somehow to be subscribed to in order to perform their logic.

My question is: which part of ngrx subscribes to effects when an action is dispatched? To put is differently who is the subscriber to effects?

Any pointer to relevant documentation or source code is welcome.

Comment: Any reason for the close? I'd be happy to edit my question if given the reason for the close...

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/v4.1.1/modules/effects/src/effects_runner.ts#L15-L21

Comment: Thanks a lot for this relevant link !